# Do C# 10 inferred delegate types involve an implicit conversion?

Tags: lambda, implicit-conversion, .net-7.0, c#-10.0, inferred-type

[Inferred delegate types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/expressions.md#1116-anonymous-function-expressions) have been introduced since [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10).

However, I am quite confused with the behavior of the feature:

Generally, I think we can reasonably expect that, if this can compile:

```
var x = (my_expression); // inferred type
SomeType y = x;
```

This single assignment should compile as well:

```
SomeType y = (my_expression);
```

However, this is not satisfied when inferred delegate types are involved:

```
using System;

class Program {

    class FunctionWrapper<Output> {
        private Func<Output> WrappedFunction { get; }
        public FunctionWrapper(Func<Output> function) => WrappedFunction = function;
        public static implicit operator FunctionWrapper<Output>(Func<Output> function) => new FunctionWrapper<Output>(function);
    }

    public delegate void DoStuffDelegate<Inout>(ref Inout Input);

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var funcLambda = () => "hello"; // type is inferred here...
        FunctionWrapper<string> funcWrapper = funcLambda;  // ... it compiles
        // but if we do a single assignment...
        FunctionWrapper<string> funcWrapper2 = () => "hello"; // CS1660 - this does not compile anymore... Why?

        // the exact opposite happens with delegates:

        // if we do a single assignment...
        DoStuffDelegate<string> delegWrapper2 = (ref string input) => { input = input + input; }; // ... it compiles
        // but if type is inferred...
        var delegateLambda = (ref string input) => { input = input + input; }; // type is inferred
        DoStuffDelegate<string> delegWrapper1 = delegateLambda; // CS0029 - this does not compile anymore...        
    }
}
```

I have the impression that inferred delegate types imply an implicit conversion at some stage, which probably should not be the case.

(link to the code: https://godbolt.org/z/3sbd9ndrT)

I tried different compilers and searched for documentation, discussions, and potential known issues regarding the behavior of inferred delegate types, unsuccessfully.

Can somebody please tell if this is a language/compiler defect, or if my expectations for these conversions to work are unreasonable?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I asked my question on csharplang github and got several detailed and comprehensive answers:
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7514

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with [`IDE0004`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0004).

You should [report this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Comment: I agree that IDE0004 is wrong in the sense that it is not aligned with compiler behavior. However, I am still questionning the language and the compiler behavior here.
If "var x = expr; SomeType y = x;" compiles, doing directly "SomeType y = expr;" should compile as well, right?

Comment: IDE0004 is not a compiler error. You can try https://sharplab.io where you won't get IDEXXXX diagnostics or a command-line compilation.

Comment: Yes, I know IDE0004 is not a compiler error. IDE0004 is not the main subject of the initial question, sorry if I was not clear. You can ignore mentions of IDE0004.
The question is about the the compilation errors indeed.

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting?

Comment: All the ones included in the code snippet I provided - If you enable the code that is commented out, you should get them as well.

Comment: You should ask more explicit and targeted questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated the question and the code snippet